# Permutation and combination on number

Tags: permutations, combinations

If $d=abc$ and $h=efg$ are two three digit numbers, then the number of pairs of $d$ and $h$ can be formed so that $d$ can be subtracted from $h$ without borrowing?

Answer (score 1):

The condition is that $a\geq e,b\geq f,c\geq g$, why?
**Hint 1:** 
Being that said we want to fix $d$ and iterate over possibilities of $h,$ so the answer would be
$$\sum _{a=1}^9\sum _{b=0}^9\sum _{c=0}^9a(b+1)(c+1),$$
notice that is not $(a+1),$ why?
This is not very interesting because is hard to compute, can you simplify? Do you see binomials appearing there?
**Hint 2:** In how many ways can you pick the $2$ elements out of $9,10,10$ possibilities in each digit? Notice that they can be different or equal and the order is given by the problem.